# Adding more options to Application Languages in Scheme Options

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode6

In xcode 6, there is a very nice feature where you can select the language you want to test your app in, without having to change the system language and restarting.
My system shows only 2 languages, how can I add more ?. I tried adding more languages in system preferences language list, but I still see the same options.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add other languages in Localizations section of your Project setting.

In the project navigator on the left, select your project (not the target). Then, click info and under the Localizations section, you will find +/- buttons to add/remove localization files. Add whichever language is needed.

After you add the language of your choice, you should be able to see it under Scheme/Application Language. For more information, you can visit Apple Developer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Art/bi_disabled_2x.png

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html

Comment: Thank you Burak!, Why I did not think of that.. seems so straightforward now.